# Grid on top of Google maps produces gaps in squares

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I have this function that produces a grid on top of Google maps.

```
var map;
var gribBlockSize = 1000;

// LOCATION MELB
var startingLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(-37.68699757550263,145.06485261920773);
var width = 10;
var height = 10;

function initialize() {
    var rectangle;
    var myOptions = {
        zoom: 10,
        center: startingLatLng,
        mapTypeControl: false,
        navigationControl: false,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
    myOptions);
    
    map.set('styles', [
        {
        "stylers": [
          { "visibility": "simplified" },
          { "saturation": -100 }
        ]
        },{
        featureType: 'road',
        elementType: 'geometry',
        stylers: [
        { color: '#333333' },
        { weight: 5 }
        ]
        }, {
        featureType: 'road',
        elementType: 'labels',
        stylers: [
            { visibility: 'on' }
          ]
        }, {
        featureType: 'landscape',
        elementType: 'geometry',
        stylers: [
            { visibility: 'on' }
          ]
        }, {
        featureType: 'poi',
        stylers: [
            { visibility: 'off' }
          ]
        }
    ]);
    
    drawRects();
} 

function drawRects () {
    var NW = startingLatLng
        
    var NS = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeOffset(NW,gribBlockSize,90)
    var SS = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeOffset(NW,gribBlockSize,180)
    
    for (var i = 0; i < height; i++) {
        NE = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeOffset(NS,i*gribBlockSize,180)
        SW = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeOffset(SS,i*gribBlockSize,180)
        
        for (var a = 0; a < width; a++) 
        {
            var path = [];
            var rectangle = new google.maps.Rectangle();
            var rectOptions = {
                bounds: new google.maps.LatLngBounds(SW,NE)
            };
            rectangle.setOptions(rectOptions);
            
            // TESTING TO GET ALL 4 CORNERS
            var NECorner = NE;
            var SWCorner = SW;
            
            var corner1 = new google.maps.LatLng(NECorner.lat(), NECorner.lng()); // NE
            var corner2 = new google.maps.LatLng(SWCorner.lat(), NECorner.lng()); // SE
            var corner3 = new google.maps.LatLng(SWCorner.lat(), SWCorner.lng()); // SW
            var corner4 = new google.maps.LatLng(NECorner.lat(), SWCorner.lng()); // NW
            
            var polygon = new google.maps.Polygon({
                strokeColor: "#FF0000",
                strokeOpacity: 0.25,
                strokeWeight: 2,
                fillColor: "#FF0000",
                fillOpacity: 0.1,
                map: map,
                paths: [corner1, corner2, corner3, corner4]
            });
            
            var NE = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeOffset(NE,gribBlockSize,90);
            var SW = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeOffset(SW,gribBlockSize,90);
        }
    }
}
```

Now the problem I am having is that if I zoom all the way in I can see gaps between the squares. This becomes a major issue when I go to produce the next grid set next to this one as the right side of the original overlaps the left side of the new set. The horizontal lines are fine, its just the vertical ones that have the gaps.

Any thoughts on how I can close these?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that the earth is an oblate spheriod (round), you need to account for that in your "grid", the top of the square needs to be shorter than the bottom if you are doing it by distance.  The simplest solution (may or may not work for your use case) is to make the verticals parallel to the lines of longitude, pre-compute the longitude at the target latitude (the latitude where you want the distance to be correct), then use the same longitudes for all the "squares".

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/su1r8uhg/)

**code snippet:**

```js
var map;
var gribBlockSize = 1000; // meters
var NEmark;

// LOCATION MELB
var startingLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(-37.68699757550263, 145.06485261920773);
var width = 10;
var height = 10;

function initialize() {
  var rectangle;
  var myOptions = {
    zoom: 10,
    center: startingLatLng,
    mapTypeControl: false,
    navigationControl: false,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
    myOptions);

  drawRects();
}

function drawRects() {
  var bounds;
  var NW = startingLatLng;
  // define horizontal lines
  var longitudes = [];
  longitudes.push(NW.lng());
  for (var i = 0; i < width; i++) {
    var longitude = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeOffset(NW, gribBlockSize, 90).lng();
    longitudes.push(longitude)
    NW = new google.maps.LatLng(NW.lat(), longitude);
  }
  var NW = startingLatLng;
  // for each longitude, make a column of squares
  for (var i = 0; i < longitudes.length - 1; i++) {
    NW = new google.maps.LatLng(startingLatLng.lat(), longitudes[i]);
    for (var j = 0; j < height; j++) {
      var north = NW.lat();
      var south = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeOffset(NW, gribBlockSize, 180).lat();
      var east = longitudes[i + 1];
      var west = longitudes[i];
      var corner1 = new google.maps.LatLng(north, east); // NE
      var corner2 = new google.maps.LatLng(south, east); // SE
      var corner3 = new google.maps.LatLng(south, west); // SW
      var corner4 = new google.maps.LatLng(north, west); // NW

      var polygon = new google.maps.Polygon({
        strokeColor: "#FF0000",
        strokeOpacity: 0.25,
        strokeWeight: 2,
        fillColor: "#FF0000",
        fillOpacity: 0.1,
        map: map,
        paths: [corner1, corner2, corner3, corner4]
      });
      NW = new google.maps.LatLng(google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeOffset(NW, gribBlockSize, 180).lat(), longitudes[i]);
    }
  }
  // map.fitBounds(bounds);
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map_canvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=geometry&key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk"></script>
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
```