# I have to implement a rectangle and polygon on maps. Divide the rectangle into grids, remove all the grids which are not a part of the polygon

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-maps

I have made a map and added a polygon to mark the boundaries of city Gurgaon. I have made a rectangle over the polygon. The task I have pending is that I have to divide this rectangle into 15*15 grids and if any grid doesn't contain any part of Gurgaon, I have to remove the specific grid. I have to display all the grids that contain some part of Gurgaon. I have my code below. 
How do I implement it?

```css
/* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
       * element that contains the map. */

#map {
  height: 100%;
}


/* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="map"></div>
<script>
  var map;
  function initMap() {
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      center: {
        lat: 28.644800,
        lng: 77.216721
      },
      zoom: 8
    });
    var rectangle = new google.maps.Rectangle({
      strokeColor: '#FF0000',
      strokeOpacity: 0.8,
      strokeWeight: 2,
      fillColor: '#FF0000',
      fillOpacity: 0.35,
      map: map,
      bounds: {
        north: 28.543048,
        south: 28.343115132,
        east: 77.14079,
        west: 76.8536989
      }
    });
    var kmlAreaData = [
      [76.8559524, 28.400185],
      [76.8696144, 28.3854157],
      [76.8796311, 28.3957333],
      [76.8877189, 28.4035728],
      [76.8925248, 28.4090852],
      [76.8928393, 28.4087934],
      [76.893404, 28.4080159],
      [76.8936004, 28.4068713],
      [76.8942142, 28.4055972],
      [76.8944107, 28.403891],
      [76.8948035, 28.4025736],
      [76.8951718, 28.4016018],
      [76.8962766, 28.4008891],
      [76.8997631, 28.399442],
      [76.901359, 28.3990533],
      [76.9035196, 28.3987293],
      [76.9066622, 28.3984054],
      [76.9072269, 28.3986213],
      [76.9186995, 28.3909024],
      [76.9214918, 28.3909756],
      [76.9216637, 28.389442],
      [76.9217213, 28.3885181],
      [76.9217923, 28.3871392],
      [76.9260805, 28.3841303],
      [76.9448805, 28.3725251],
      [76.9471551, 28.3716597],
      [76.948573, 28.3709873],
      [76.9515171, 28.3693086],
      [76.9522659, 28.3687944],
      [76.9516175, 28.3671617],
      [76.9516565, 28.3665591],
      [76.9523096, 28.3655348],
      [76.9523001, 28.3651476],
      [76.9522603, 28.3643684],
      [76.9523877, 28.3636001],
      [76.9525249, 28.3622109],
      [76.9527433, 28.3614269],
      [76.9532313, 28.3605505],
      [76.9537915, 28.3600506],
      [76.9542382, 28.3594186],
      [76.9545178, 28.3591334],
      [76.9552684, 28.3585701],
      [76.9571494, 28.3570005],
      [76.9561195, 28.3569945],
      [76.9561191, 28.3564473],
      [76.9573246, 28.3565013],
      [76.9573267, 28.356607],
      [76.9573286, 28.3567014],
      [76.9583386, 28.3566958],
      [76.9584105, 28.3610635],
      [76.9601282, 28.3610604],
      [76.9638667, 28.3610535],
      [76.9642001, 28.3610529],
      [76.9651835, 28.3615682],
      [76.9655589, 28.3618005],
      [76.9659736, 28.3620599],
      [76.9663627, 28.3620514],
      [76.9671707, 28.3592872],
      [76.9674586, 28.3587191],
      [76.9862863, 28.3472344],
      [77.0043215, 28.3882571],
      [77.015501, 28.3830638],
      [77.0144066, 28.3799885],
      [77.0220731, 28.3737851],
      [77.0255131, 28.3775172],
      [77.0361475, 28.3681112],
      [77.0471875, 28.3583116],
      [77.1188819, 28.3701088],
      [77.1146418, 28.3983352],
      [77.138683, 28.4072441],
      [77.1287009, 28.4404645],
      [77.1277292, 28.4428335],
      [77.1253919, 28.4502107],
      [77.1242593, 28.4510201],
      [77.1238974, 28.4550376],
      [77.1234764, 28.4597104],
      [77.1200235, 28.4627232],
      [77.116455, 28.4672235],
      [77.1124725, 28.4731841],
      [77.1141826, 28.4735236],
      [77.1150614, 28.4815648],
      [77.1167211, 28.4850054],
      [77.1176759, 28.4869846],
      [77.119507, 28.495139],
      [77.1124785, 28.4984532],
      [77.1101397, 28.4993961],
      [77.1053975, 28.5013384],
      [77.1037667, 28.5024887],
      [77.1023081, 28.5031016],
      [77.1000336, 28.5038653],
      [77.0976518, 28.5048552],
      [77.0957528, 28.5070803],
      [77.0986588, 28.5114068],
      [77.0939182, 28.5138682],
      [77.0932384, 28.5140471],
      [77.0925943, 28.5142311],
      [77.0859574, 28.5161025],
      [77.0846262, 28.5164992],
      [77.0840906, 28.5166587],
      [77.0830606, 28.5169698],
      [77.0827494, 28.5170898],
      [77.0804111, 28.5180224],
      [77.0792948, 28.5182048],
      [77.0792318, 28.5182128],
      [77.0774387, 28.5184405],
      [77.075014, 28.5187138],
      [77.0747744, 28.5188088],
      [77.0744668, 28.5189307],
      [77.073365, 28.5195071],
      [77.0723002, 28.5202589],
      [77.0722213, 28.5201457],
      [77.0720942, 28.5193619],
      [77.0713662, 28.5175938],
      [77.0709886, 28.5170499],
      [77.0688651, 28.5145822],
      [77.067616, 28.5129745],
      [77.0671624, 28.5119289],
      [77.0653494, 28.5125045],
      [77.0645251, 28.5126891],
      [77.0633996, 28.5126665],
      [77.0612165, 28.512224],
      [77.0606606, 28.5122555],
      [77.0577011, 28.5127924],
      [77.0575428, 28.5128211],
      [77.0543531, 28.5143512],
      [77.0491721, 28.5160453],
      [77.0462065, 28.5166427],
      [77.0485082, 28.52092],
      [77.0446105, 28.5230838],
      [77.0433705, 28.5241645],
      [77.0433583, 28.5251547],
      [77.0431514, 28.5252371],
      [77.0424046, 28.5256984],
      [77.0417144, 28.5260711],
      [77.0356349, 28.5292442],
      [77.0356102, 28.5292571],
      [77.0340499, 28.5300715],
      [77.0321199, 28.5310788],
      [77.0298669, 28.5316849],
      [77.0297824, 28.5317014],
      [77.0245904, 28.5327132],
      [77.0232547, 28.5335616],
      [77.0219253, 28.5347748],
      [77.0217025, 28.5349596],
      [77.0197006, 28.536218],
      [77.0174236, 28.537688],
      [77.0162809, 28.5392112],
      [77.0140944, 28.5399982],
      [77.0134571, 28.5405156],
      [77.0128497, 28.5402697],
      [77.0122093, 28.5400104],
      [77.0101934, 28.5402687],
      [77.0096859, 28.539869],
      [77.0086334, 28.5403299],
      [77.0076539, 28.5397729],
      [77.0054602, 28.5394958],
      [77.0043849, 28.537795],
      [77.0016644, 28.5334918],
      [77.0013296, 28.5309864],
      [77.0016511, 28.5308084],
      [77.0050118, 28.528947],
      [77.0084757, 28.5270284],
      [77.0096001, 28.526641],
      [77.0105771, 28.5257745],
      [77.0109605, 28.5254514],
      [77.0146291, 28.5243485],
      [77.0169637, 28.5210774],
      [77.0144723, 28.518757],
      [77.012884, 28.5172777],
      [77.0125538, 28.5169701],
      [77.0116413, 28.5161518],
      [77.0108262, 28.5154209],
      [77.0105264, 28.5151521],
      [77.010493, 28.5151221],
      [77.0100507, 28.5147255],
      [77.0085304, 28.5151415],
      [77.0070407, 28.515549],
      [77.0067265, 28.515635],
      [77.0059192, 28.5158559],
      [77.0027227, 28.5172931],
      [76.9999924, 28.5179713],
      [76.9990215, 28.5184832],
      [76.9968081, 28.5197124],
      [76.9959691, 28.5180316],
      [76.9953859, 28.5171445],
      [76.9945276, 28.5176083],
      [76.9909463, 28.5135677],
      [76.983382, 28.5169891],
      [76.9832794, 28.5170355],
      [76.9812139, 28.5191174],
      [76.9802327, 28.5198029],
      [76.9783615, 28.5212481],
      [76.9760102, 28.5189385],
      [76.9706299, 28.515795],
      [76.9620491, 28.5115276],
      [76.9648243, 28.509661],
      [76.9762078, 28.4984432],
      [76.9720448, 28.4914468],
      [76.9692444, 28.4860356],
      [76.9665067, 28.4806004],
      [76.9654443, 28.4787172],
      [76.9642444, 28.4765902],
      [76.9607315, 28.4705733],
      [76.9581786, 28.468231],
      [76.9537542, 28.4642338],
      [76.9453408, 28.4568557],
      [76.9465866, 28.4442302],
      [76.9069895, 28.4252864],
      [76.8616645, 28.4410796],
      [76.8671319, 28.4182734],
      [76.869179, 28.4060588],
      [76.8559524, 28.400185]
    ];
    var coords = buildCoordinatesArrayFromString(kmlAreaData);

    function buildCoordinatesArrayFromString(MultiGeometryCoordinates) {
      var finalData = [];
      MultiGeometryCoordinates.forEach(function(item, i) {
        finalData.push({
          lng: parseFloat(item[0]),
          lat: parseFloat(item[1])
        });
      });
      return finalData;
    }
    var polygon = new google.maps.Polygon({
      paths: coords,
      strokeColor: '#0037FF',
      strokeOpacity: 0.8,
      strokeWeight: 3
    });
    polygon.setMap(map);
  }
</script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBdPTn6zjYe28lYdTxA_76YPhebeKlmPIQ&callback=initMap"></script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. create your 15x15 grid.  Following function is modified from an answer to [Grid on top of Google maps produces gaps in squares](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38493098/grid-on-top-of-google-maps-produces-gaps-in-squares/38494172#38494172)

```
function drawRects(bounds, verticalBlocks, horizontalBlocks) {
  var startingLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(bounds.getNorthEast().lat(),
    bounds.getSouthWest().lng());
  var NWcorner = new google.maps.LatLng(bounds.getNorthEast().lat(),
    bounds.getSouthWest().lng());
  var SWcorner = bounds.getSouthWest();
  var verticalBlockSize = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(NWcorner, SWcorner) / verticalBlocks;
  var NEcorner = bounds.getNorthEast();
  var horizontalBlockSize = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(NWcorner, NEcorner) / verticalBlocks;

  // modified from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38493098/grid-on-top-of-google-maps-produces-gaps-in-squares/38494172#38494172
  var NW = startingLatLng;
  // define horizontal lines
  var longitudes = [];
  longitudes.push(NW.lng());
  for (var i = 0; i < verticalBlocks; i++) {
    var longitude = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeOffset(NW, horizontalBlockSize, 90).lng();
    longitudes.push(longitude)
    NW = new google.maps.LatLng(NW.lat(), longitude);
  }
  var NW = startingLatLng;
  // for each longitude, make a column of squares
  for (var i = 0; i < longitudes.length - 1; i++) {
    NW = new google.maps.LatLng(startingLatLng.lat(), longitudes[i]);
    for (var j = 0; j < horizontalBlocks; j++) {
      var north = NW.lat();
      var south = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeOffset(NW, verticalBlockSize, 180).lat();
      var east = longitudes[i + 1];
      var west = longitudes[i];
      var corner1 = new google.maps.LatLng(north, east); // NE
      var corner2 = new google.maps.LatLng(south, east); // SE
      var corner3 = new google.maps.LatLng(south, west); // SW
      var corner4 = new google.maps.LatLng(north, west); // NW

      var polygon = new google.maps.Polygon({
        strokeColor: "#FF0000",
        strokeOpacity: 0.25,
        strokeWeight: 2,
        fillColor: "#FF0000",
        fillOpacity: 0.1,
        map: map,
        paths: [corner1, corner2, corner3, corner4]
      });
      polygons.push(polygon);
      NW = new google.maps.LatLng(south, longitudes[i]);
    }
  }
}
```

2. process through those rectangles and determine whether they contain any part of the input polygon

```
// find boundary squares
for (var i = 0; i < polygons.length; i++) {
  var hidePoly = true;
  for (var j = 0; j < polygon.getPath().getLength(); j++) {
    if (google.maps.geometry.poly.containsLocation(polygon.getPath().getAt(j), polygons[i])) {
      console.log("polygons[" + i + "] contains " + polygon.getPath().getAt(j));
      hidePoly = false
      break;
    }
  }
  if (hidePoly) polygons[i].setMap(null);
}
// find internal squares
for (var j = 0; j < polygon.getPath().getLength(); j++) {
  for (var i = 0; i < polygons.length; i++) {
    for (var k = 0; k < polygons[i].getPath().getLength(); k++) {
      if (google.maps.geometry.poly.containsLocation(polygons[i].getPath().getAt(k), polygon)) {
        console.log("polygon contains polygons[" + i + "]=" + polygons[i].getPath().getAt(k));
        polygons[i].setMap(map)
        break;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

[proof of concept fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/8sjgtkvw/4/)

[image: screenshot of resulting map]

**code snippet:**

```css
html,
body,
#map {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="map"></div>
<script>
  var map;

  function initMap() {
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      center: {
        lat: 28.644800,
        lng: 77.216721
      },
      zoom: 8
    });
    var rectangle = new google.maps.Rectangle({
      strokeColor: '#0000FF',
      strokeOpacity: 0.8,
      strokeWeight: 2,
      fillColor: '#0000FF',
      fillOpacity: 0.2,
      map: map,
      bounds: {
        north: 28.543048,
        south: 28.343115132,
        east: 77.14079,
        west: 76.8536989
      }
    });
    var kmlAreaData = [[76.8559524, 28.400185],[76.8696144, 28.3854157],[76.8796311, 28.3957333],[76.8877189, 28.4035728],[76.8925248, 28.4090852],[76.8928393, 28.4087934],[76.893404, 28.4080159],[76.8936004, 28.4068713],[76.8942142, 28.4055972],[76.8944107, 28.403891],[76.8948035, 28.4025736],[76.8951718, 28.4016018],[76.8962766, 28.4008891],[76.8997631, 28.399442],[76.901359, 28.3990533],[76.9035196, 28.3987293],[76.9066622, 28.3984054],[76.9072269, 28.3986213],[76.9186995, 28.3909024],[76.9214918, 28.3909756],[76.9216637, 28.389442],[76.9217213, 28.3885181],[76.9217923, 28.3871392],[76.9260805, 28.3841303],[76.9448805, 28.3725251],[76.9471551, 28.3716597],[76.948573, 28.3709873],[76.9515171, 28.3693086],[76.9522659, 28.3687944],[76.9516175, 28.3671617],[76.9516565, 28.3665591],[76.9523096, 28.3655348],[76.9523001, 28.3651476],[76.9522603, 28.3643684],[76.9523877, 28.3636001],[76.9525249, 28.3622109],[76.9527433, 28.3614269],[76.9532313, 28.3605505],[76.9537915, 28.3600506],[76.9542382, 28.3594186],[76.9545178, 28.3591334],[76.9552684, 28.3585701],[76.9571494, 28.3570005],[76.9561195, 28.3569945],[76.9561191, 28.3564473],[76.9573246, 28.3565013],[76.9573267, 28.356607],[76.9573286, 28.3567014],[76.9583386, 28.3566958],[76.9584105, 28.3610635],[76.9601282, 28.3610604],[76.9638667, 28.3610535],[76.9642001, 28.3610529],[76.9651835, 28.3615682],[76.9655589, 28.3618005],[76.9659736, 28.3620599],[76.9663627, 28.3620514],[76.9671707, 28.3592872],[76.9674586, 28.3587191],[76.9862863, 28.3472344],[77.0043215, 28.3882571],[77.015501, 28.3830638],[77.0144066, 28.3799885],[77.0220731, 28.3737851],[77.0255131, 28.3775172],[77.0361475, 28.3681112],[77.0471875, 28.3583116],[77.1188819, 28.3701088],[77.1146418, 28.3983352],[77.138683, 28.4072441],[77.1287009, 28.4404645],[77.1277292, 28.4428335],[77.1253919, 28.4502107],[77.1242593, 28.4510201],[77.1238974, 28.4550376],[77.1234764, 28.4597104],[77.1200235, 28.4627232],[77.116455, 28.4672235],[77.1124725, 28.4731841],[77.1141826, 28.4735236],[77.1150614, 28.4815648],[77.1167211, 28.4850054],[77.1176759, 28.4869846],[77.119507, 28.495139],[77.1124785, 28.4984532],[77.1101397, 28.4993961],[77.1053975, 28.5013384],[77.1037667, 28.5024887],[77.1023081, 28.5031016],[77.1000336, 28.5038653],[77.0976518, 28.5048552],[77.0957528, 28.5070803],[77.0986588, 28.5114068],[77.0939182, 28.5138682],[77.0932384, 28.5140471],[77.0925943, 28.5142311],[77.0859574, 28.5161025],[77.0846262, 28.5164992],[77.0840906, 28.5166587],[77.0830606, 28.5169698],[77.0827494, 28.5170898],[77.0804111, 28.5180224],[77.0792948, 28.5182048],[77.0792318, 28.5182128],[77.0774387, 28.5184405],[77.075014, 28.5187138],[77.0747744, 28.5188088],[77.0744668, 28.5189307],[77.073365, 28.5195071],[77.0723002, 28.5202589],[77.0722213, 28.5201457],[77.0720942, 28.5193619],[77.0713662, 28.5175938],[77.0709886, 28.5170499],[77.0688651, 28.5145822],[77.067616, 28.5129745],[77.0671624, 28.5119289],[77.0653494, 28.5125045],[77.0645251, 28.5126891],[77.0633996, 28.5126665],[77.0612165, 28.512224],[77.0606606, 28.5122555],[77.0577011, 28.5127924],[77.0575428, 28.5128211],[77.0543531, 28.5143512],[77.0491721, 28.5160453],[77.0462065, 28.5166427],[77.0485082, 28.52092],[77.0446105, 28.5230838],[77.0433705, 28.5241645],[77.0433583, 28.5251547],[77.0431514, 28.5252371],[77.0424046, 28.5256984],[77.0417144, 28.5260711],[77.0356349, 28.5292442],[77.0356102, 28.5292571],[77.0340499, 28.5300715],[77.0321199, 28.5310788],[77.0298669, 28.5316849],[77.0297824, 28.5317014],[77.0245904, 28.5327132],[77.0232547, 28.5335616],[77.0219253, 28.5347748],[77.0217025, 28.5349596],[77.0197006, 28.536218],[77.0174236, 28.537688],[77.0162809, 28.5392112],[77.0140944, 28.5399982],[77.0134571, 28.5405156],[77.0128497, 28.5402697],[77.0122093, 28.5400104],[77.0101934, 28.5402687],[77.0096859, 28.539869],[77.0086334, 28.5403299],[77.0076539, 28.5397729],[77.0054602, 28.5394958],[77.0043849, 28.537795],[77.0016644, 28.5334918],[77.0013296, 28.5309864],[77.0016511, 28.5308084],[77.0050118, 28.528947],[77.0084757, 28.5270284],[77.0096001, 28.526641],[77.0105771, 28.5257745],[77.0109605, 28.5254514],[77.0146291, 28.5243485],[77.0169637, 28.5210774],[77.0144723, 28.518757],[77.012884, 28.5172777],[77.0125538, 28.5169701],[77.0116413, 28.5161518],[77.0108262, 28.5154209],[77.0105264, 28.5151521],[77.010493, 28.5151221],[77.0100507, 28.5147255],[77.0085304, 28.5151415],[77.0070407, 28.515549],[77.0067265, 28.515635],[77.0059192, 28.5158559],[77.0027227, 28.5172931],[76.9999924, 28.5179713],[76.9990215, 28.5184832],[76.9968081, 28.5197124],[76.9959691, 28.5180316],[76.9953859, 28.5171445],[76.9945276, 28.5176083],[76.9909463, 28.5135677],[76.983382, 28.5169891],[76.9832794, 28.5170355],[76.9812139, 28.5191174],[76.9802327, 28.5198029],[76.9783615, 28.5212481],[76.9760102, 28.5189385],[76.9706299, 28.515795],[76.9620491, 28.5115276],[76.9648243, 28.509661],[76.9762078, 28.4984432],[76.9720448, 28.4914468],[76.9692444, 28.4860356],[76.9665067, 28.4806004],[76.9654443, 28.4787172],[76.9642444, 28.4765902],[76.9607315, 28.4705733],[76.9581786, 28.468231],[76.9537542, 28.4642338],[76.9453408, 28.4568557],[76.9465866, 28.4442302],[76.9069895, 28.4252864],[76.8616645, 28.4410796],[76.8671319, 28.4182734],[76.869179, 28.4060588],[76.8559524, 28.400185]];
    
    var coords = buildCoordinatesArrayFromString(kmlAreaData);

    function buildCoordinatesArrayFromString(MultiGeometryCoordinates) {
      var finalData = [];
      MultiGeometryCoordinates.forEach(function(item, i) {
        finalData.push({
          lng: parseFloat(item[0]),
          lat: parseFloat(item[1])
        });
      });
      return finalData;
    }
    var polygon = new google.maps.Polygon({
      paths: coords,
      strokeColor: '#0037FF',
      strokeOpacity: 0.8,
      strokeWeight: 3
    });
    polygon.setMap(map);
    drawRects(rectangle.getBounds(), 15, 15);
    map.fitBounds(rectangle.getBounds());
    // find boundary squares
    for (var i = 0; i < polygons.length; i++) {
      var hidePoly = true;
      for (var j = 0; j < polygon.getPath().getLength(); j++) {
        if (google.maps.geometry.poly.containsLocation(polygon.getPath().getAt(j), polygons[i])) {
          console.log("polygons[" + i + "] contains " + polygon.getPath().getAt(j));
          hidePoly = false
          break;
        }
      }
      if (hidePoly) polygons[i].setMap(null);
    }
    // find internal squares
    for (var j = 0; j < polygon.getPath().getLength(); j++) {
      for (var i = 0; i < polygons.length; i++) {
        for (var k = 0; k < polygons[i].getPath().getLength(); k++) {
          if (google.maps.geometry.poly.containsLocation(polygons[i].getPath().getAt(k), polygon)) {
            console.log("polygon contains polygons[" + i + "]=" + polygons[i].getPath().getAt(k));
            polygons[i].setMap(map)
            break;
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  var polygons = [];

  function drawRects(bounds, verticalBlocks, horizontalBlocks) {
    var startingLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(bounds.getNorthEast().lat(),
      bounds.getSouthWest().lng());
    var NWcorner = new google.maps.LatLng(bounds.getNorthEast().lat(),
      bounds.getSouthWest().lng());
    var SWcorner = bounds.getSouthWest();
    var verticalBlockSize = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(NWcorner, SWcorner) / verticalBlocks;
    var NEcorner = bounds.getNorthEast();
    var horizontalBlockSize = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(NWcorner, NEcorner) / verticalBlocks;

    var width = 10;
    var height = 10;
    // modified from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38493098/grid-on-top-of-google-maps-produces-gaps-in-squares/38494172#38494172
    var bounds;
    var NW = startingLatLng;
    // define horizontal lines
    var longitudes = [];
    longitudes.push(NW.lng());
    for (var i = 0; i < verticalBlocks; i++) {
      var longitude = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeOffset(NW, horizontalBlockSize, 90).lng();
      longitudes.push(longitude)
      NW = new google.maps.LatLng(NW.lat(), longitude);
    }
    var NW = startingLatLng;
    // for each longitude, make a column of squares
    for (var i = 0; i < longitudes.length - 1; i++) {
      NW = new google.maps.LatLng(startingLatLng.lat(), longitudes[i]);
      for (var j = 0; j < horizontalBlocks; j++) {
        var north = NW.lat();
        var south = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeOffset(NW, verticalBlockSize, 180).lat();
        var east = longitudes[i + 1];
        var west = longitudes[i];
        var corner1 = new google.maps.LatLng(north, east); // NE
        var corner2 = new google.maps.LatLng(south, east); // SE
        var corner3 = new google.maps.LatLng(south, west); // SW
        var corner4 = new google.maps.LatLng(north, west); // NW

        var polygon = new google.maps.Polygon({
          strokeColor: "#FF0000",
          strokeOpacity: 0.25,
          strokeWeight: 2,
          fillColor: "#FF0000",
          fillOpacity: 0.1,
          map: map,
          paths: [corner1, corner2, corner3, corner4]
        });
        polygons.push(polygon);
        NW = new google.maps.LatLng(south, longitudes[i]);
      }
    }
  }
</script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=geometry&key=AIzaSyBdPTn6zjYe28lYdTxA_76YPhebeKlmPIQ&callback=initMap"></script>
```