# How to create grid with size in meters

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I am currently working with the Google Maps API v3 and have successfully created a grid on the map. However, I am facing an issue.

I have implemented functionality to take user input for the quantity of grids (e.g., 3x3 or 5x5). Now, I want to allow users to specify the size of each grid, such as setting the width of each grid column to 5 meters.

How can I implement this in my Google Maps API v3 project? Any guidance or code examples would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

This is my create grid function,

```js
function startGridGeneration() {
  if (gridGenerated) {
    alert("Grid has already been generated.");
    return;
  }
  // alert("Place the marker on map.");

  google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'click', function(event) {
    addFirstMarker(event.latLng);
  });
}

function addFirstMarker(location) {
  marker1 = new google.maps.Marker({ // Change from marker to marker1
    position: location,
    map: map,
    title: 'Start Point'
  });
  markers.push(marker1);
  google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'click', function(event) {
    addSecondMarker(event.latLng);
  });
}

function addSecondMarker(location) {
  marker2 = new google.maps.Marker({ // Change from marker to marker2
    position: location,
    map: map,
    title: 'Target Location'
  });
  markers.push(marker2);
  var quantity = prompt("Enter the quantity for the grid (e.g., 3 for a 3x3 grid):");
  quantity = parseInt(quantity);
  if (isNaN(quantity) || quantity <= 0) {
    alert("Invalid input. Please enter a positive number for the grid quantity.");
    return;
  }
  updateButtonClasses("grid_generation", "btn-success", "btn-success");

  makeGrid(quantity);
  gridGenerated = true;
}

function makeGrid(quantity) {
  if (markers.length < 2) {
    alert("Please add at least two markers before creating the grid.");
    return;
  }
  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
  markers.forEach(function(marker) {
    bounds.extend(marker.getPosition());
  });

  var leftSideDist = bounds.getNorthEast().lng() - bounds.getSouthWest().lng(); // horizontal
  var aboveSideDist = bounds.getNorthEast().lat() - bounds.getSouthWest().lat(); // verticcal
  var dividerLat = quantity;
  var dividerLng = quantity;
  var excLat = aboveSideDist / dividerLat;
  var excLng = leftSideDist / dividerLng;

  // Add a fixed marker at 1,1 grid point
  fixedMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(bounds.getNorthEast().lat() - (excLat / 2), bounds.getSouthWest().lng() + (excLng / 2)),
    map: map,
    title: 'Start Point',
    label: {
      color: 'white',
      fontWeight: 'bold',
      text: 'Start Point',
    },
  });

  for (var i = 0; i < dividerLat; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < dividerLng; j++) {
      var buttonBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
        new google.maps.LatLng(bounds.getNorthEast().lat() - (excLat * (i + 1)), bounds.getSouthWest().lng() + (excLng * j)),
        new google.maps.LatLng(bounds.getNorthEast().lat() - (excLat * i), bounds.getSouthWest().lng() + (excLng * (j + 1)))
      );

      rectangle = new google.maps.Rectangle({
        strokeOpacity: 0.3,
        strokeWeight: 1,
        fillOpacity: 0,
        map: map,
        bounds: buttonBounds
      });

      attachRectangleClickEvent(rectangle, bounds.getNorthEast().lat() - (excLat * i) - excLat / 2, bounds.getSouthWest().lng() + (excLng * j) + excLng / 2);
    }
  }
  marker1.setMap(null);
  marker2.setMap(null);
}
```

Comment: Where do you want that 5 meters to be?  The top of the square, the center of the square or the bottom of the square?  If you check your existing grid,  my guess is that all three of those are different lengths (unless the grid cell spans the equator).

Comment: Although for a 5x5 meter grid, the difference is pretty small.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Grid on top of Google maps produces gaps in squares](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38493098/grid-on-top-of-google-maps-produces-gaps-in-squares)

Comment: Hi geocodezip... what im trying to do is,
user will come at this page, click on startGridGeneration button,
it will take 1st marker and 2nd marker, after placing 2nd marker it will take input from user for grid quantity and based on that it will create the create... Evreything is working fine as expected...
so what i wanted to add is to take size of the grid, For example if user add 5*5 quantity and 5 as size then it should create grid of 5*5 grid and every grid columns should be 5 meters in size...